# HTTP Error 307 in Android after Moving to New Server

Tags: android, server

We have developed an application on Android using **Asynctask** to retrieve data from backend which is working great. Then, the application has been moved to another **new server**. after that, **most of the time** when we are trying to connect to the server, we are getting **307** (Temporary Redirect) HTTP error. Although we have the same application that is developed for iOS and it is working fine with the new server.

Currently, I have tried running the Android application using the URL for the old server and it is working great. At the same time, when I’m using the URL for the new server the problem still persists.

So I need to know is it a problem with the server configuration or it is a problem with that connection library that I’m using.

```
    public void getData(MainModel mainModel) {

        this.mainModel = mainModel;
        requestURL = " ........";
        postString = "........";

        execute();
    }


    public HttpURLConnection POSTConnection(String postString) {

        URL url = null;
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;

        try {
            url = new URL(requestURL);

            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
            out.print(postString);
            out.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            exception(e);
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {

            exception(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {

            exception(e);

        }

        return httpURLConnection;
    }

    public String JSONResponse(HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection) {

        int statusCode = 0;
        StringBuilder response;
        byte[] data = null;
        String responseString = null;

        try {

            statusCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();

            if (statusCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader
                        (httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));

                response = new StringBuilder();

                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(line);
                }

                data = response.toString().getBytes();
                responseString = new String(data);

            } else {

                POSTConnection(postString);
                data = null;
            }


        } catch (IOException e) {

            exception(e);
        }

        return responseString;

    }


protected ArrayList<....Model> doInBackground(Void... params) {

    ArrayList<.....Model> myList = null;

    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = POSTConnection(postString);

    if (httpURLConnection != null) {

        String responseString = JSONResponse(httpURLConnection);

        if (responseString != null) {

            myList = parseJSONResponse(responseString);

        }

        httpURLConnection.disconnect();
    }

    return .......;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Edit the question to include the code that makes the HTTP request so we can see how you are setting it up

Comment: @hardillb I've added the HTTP request

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(boolean)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setFollowRedirects(boolean)) method

You should be able to add the following to your code:

```
httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

httpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);

httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Comment: I've added this line. the problem is, it takes almost 2 minutes to retrieve the data from the server. Is there any other solution?